# What R package is %<>% from

Tags: r

When I used R a number of years ago I was using %<>% when writing code and I no longer remember which package it comes from. A google search has not provided me with the answer either.

I thought it might be dplyr but it is not.

Comment: It's from the magrittr package: https://magrittr.tidyverse.org/articles/magrittr.html#additional-pipe-operators

Comment: It comes from magrittr